# shiny server can not show dashboard body functions

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I install shiny server on centos 7 and run example project and its seems OK

but when I try to deploy R project (that have dashboardbody functions), I see below error in shiny server log files:

```
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:41240
Warning: Error in dashboardBody: could not find function "dashboardBody"
  [No stack trace available]
```

I install Rstudio and try to run application in it. every things seems OK but in shiny server I can not deploy it.

ui.R

```
body <- dashboardBody(tags$head(
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")
),
fluidRow(
  gradientBox(
    title = "test",
    boxToolSize = "sm",
    collapsible = FALSE,
    footer = (tagList(
      br(),
      numericInput(
        "threshhold",
        "test",
        width = 150,
        min = 0.001 ,
        value = 0.9,
        max = 1,
        step = 0.01
      ),
      actionButton(inputId = "run", label = "test"),
      actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "test"),
      plotlyOutput("fraude_value")
    ))
  ),
  gradientBox(
    title = "test",
    boxToolSize = "sm",
    collapsible = FALSE,
    footer = (tagList(
      br(),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "transaction_info")
    ))
  )
),fluidRow(
  gradientBox(
    title = "test",
    boxToolSize = "sm",
    collapsible = FALSE,
    footer = (tagList(
      br(),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "fraud_info")
    )),
    width = 12
  )
))
# ,
# footer = p(textOutput("currentTime", container = span)))




ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "purple",
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                   disable = TRUE),
  body
)
```

Comment: seems like a standard missing library error, please post `server.R` and `ui.R`

Comment: add my ui.R @PorkChop

Comment: add all the libraries to the `ui.r`

Comment: Specifically you need to add "library(shinydashboard)"

Comment: thanks a lot , I write all library in app.R but the source(ui.r) needs to have full path in server.

Answer (score 0):

Be explicit in your call in ui.R

```
shinydashboard::dashboardBody(...)
```

Also, make sure that the shinydashboard package is installed in a library path that is accessible to the R session that is initiated by the Shiny Server. For example, if you installed the package as a non-root user it may have installed into a personal library (i.e. ~/R/win-library/3.5). If the Shiny Server is started as another user, even as root, that personal library may not be in the Shiny Server R session library search path. You can check the library search path by running `.libPaths()`.